# Tracing paths in a Graph between two nodes

Tags: graph, path, adjacency-matrix

How to trace the paths between two nodes in a given graph once if we know or donot know the length of the path between them?( By considering Adjacency matrix)

Between Adjacency matrix and breadth first search in finding the paths which one is efficient?

Can you please give the algorithm steps.

Thank you in Advance,
Kamala.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer would depend on what kind of path you're searching for.

If you are searching for a shortest path, then you can try implementing [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/software/AlgAnim/dijkstra.html), which also runs very fast.

If you are just trying to find a path, no matter it's length, then [BFS](http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Breadth-first_search.html) is a nice solution, since it will find it in the "shallowest" place, though it doesn't guarantee that it is the shortest one.

Other options for you are [DFS](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960215.html), which will search first for the deepest paths and [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman-Ford_algorithm), which will also give the shortest path, but in more general scenarios than Dijkstra's, so it will be slower.

If you want all possible paths, then any of these algorithms can be reimplemented to perform a marking of the graph, and so get all possible paths.